# How many ways are there to decompose a cycle into paths of given lengths?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I believe this to be a question in Combinatorics. To state more formally, given a labeled cycle graph with $n$ vertices $C_{n}$ and parameters $a_{1}, ..., a_{k}$, such that $a_{1}+...+a_{k}=n$. How many ways can we decompose $C_{n}$ into consecutive paths of lengths $a_{1}, ..., a_{k}$?

In my thought, it would be relevant to the values of $a_{1}, ..., a_{k}$. Define $\sigma$ to be the order of $a_{1}, ..., a_{k}$, which means $\sigma$ is the minimal positive integer, such that $a_{1}=a_{1+\sigma(mod k)}$, ..., $a_{k}=a_{k+\sigma(mod k)}$. Then the number of ways would be $\frac{n\sigma}{k}$.

I wonder if there is an explicit formula for this. I didn't find relevant questions and wonder if that's because my improper way of statement.

Comment: Surround your math with $ signs to make it work.

Comment: By saying the cyclic graph is labelled, do you mean to count two partitions one which can be rotated less than 360 to the other as different? Also have you tried your formula $n\sigma/k$ on some small examples where one can write all the ways down?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I mean two partitions are not the same by rotating. But I think the case you mentioned would be like Stirling number of the second kind. And I have verified on some graphs.